# How to put a button next to a selected item of a TTreeView at run-time?

Tags: delphi, treeview

I have a TreeView that contains groups of information like projects, clients, operators and regions. Their children items are rows from each group in the database. Whenever I double-click an item, it changes the table on the other side of the screen filtering the table results by the item I just selected in the TreeView.

As those TreeViews are in fact items of a database table, I would like to open another windows to edit the selected item by clicking in a button that would appear next the item, just outside the TreeView so the button doesn't cover the text of the item.

**Question is,** how to know the exact position of the selected item in the TreeView **?**

***Please consider,*** *that may the enough items to make the vertical scroll bar to appear or not. And I can not use a pop-up menu to do this.*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use an item's [`DisplayRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.DisplayRect) method passing a parameter of 'true' for the item's text's bounding rectangle in client coordinates. Compare this rectangle to one obtained with a parameter of 'false', and you'll know if there is enough space to draw a button on the right of the item text.

Comment: Very good, but unfortunately I tried and then discovered that the TreeView version I use do not have this `DisplayRect` method. Is is the TUniTreeView, bacause I am developing a web application in UniGUI framework.